# Why $e^{i\theta}$ has range in bounded values?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

In other words why raising $n^{th}$ power of a point on the unit circle again gives a point on the same circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the identity
$$|zw|=|z|\cdot|w|$$
where $w$ and $z$ are complex numbers. So if $|z|=1$ we have
$$|z^n|=|z|^n=1$$
so $z^n$ also lies on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $e^{i\phi}$ has absolut value $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write any complex number as $r e^{i\phi}$, where $r$ is a non-negative real number. When raised to $n$-th power, you get $r^n e^{in\phi}$. But in your case $r=1$, so raising to $n$-th power will yield $e^{in\phi}$, which is still on the unit circle,